# how to sort output lines from ReadAllLines? should be strings[] $lines?

Tags: powershell

The following code gives me an error on the Sort Function from PowerShell:

```
function Sorter {
    param(
        [string]$InFile = ""
    )

    $FP = Resolve-Path $InFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable fp2
    if (-not($FP)) {
        throw "In file not found: $InFile";
    }

    $lines = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($FP)
    
    $lines.Sort()
}
```

PS> Sorter -InFile C:\Windows\win.ini

ERROR!!! on line $lines.Sort()

strings[] $lines should have a Sort Method?

Comment: Is this a cleansed version of your actual code? You currently have an extra curly brace `}`.

Comment: On a side note `Resolve-Path` can return more than one path when you call the function with wildcards, e. g. `Sorter *.txt`. Either error out, when `$FP.Count -gt 1` or loop over the files.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Sort-Object` cmdlet:

```
$lines = $lines |Sort-Object
```

`Sort-Object` is (indirectly) type-aware and will correctly sort the values alphabetically (as they are strings).

Answer (score 1):

*Arrays* don't have a `.Sort()` *instance* method, but the [`[Array]` type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Array) has a *static* `.Sort()` method for *in-place* sorting.

```sh
# Simulate the result from a [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines() call
[string[]] $arr = 'box', 'aha', 'zebra', 'fox'

# Sort the array *in place*.
[Array]::Sort($arr) # No output, but $arr is now sorted.

$arr # -> 'aha', 'box', 'fox', 'zebra'
```

All other approaches will result in degraded performance:

- Your [own solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70789099/45375) requires constructing a [`` System.Collections.Generic.List`1 ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.List-1) instance from the original array, whose `.Sort()` *instance* method can then be used.
- Piping to [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object), which, when captured in a variable, constructs a *new* array, invariably of type `[object[]]`, is both PowerShell-idiomatic and convenient, but *especially slow*.

---

That said, if you output a collection *from a PowerShell function or script*, it is *enumerated*, so that its elements are emitted *one by one* to the pipeline.

If the caller were to capture the result in a variable, the result would again be an `[object[]]` array - with *two or more* elements - or - with a *single* element - that single element *as-is*.

In order to emit a collection *as a whole*, you need to use either `Write-Output -NoEnumerate $arr` or - more succinctly and efficiently, but also more obscurely, using the unary form of `,`, the [array constructor operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-) - `, $arr`.

While this improves performance, do note that it contravenes the standard expectation that PowerShell commands emit objects *one by one*.

Answer (score 0):

Type `String` does not have a sort method.

However you can pipe the `$Lines` through to the Sort Function / Cmdlet:

```
function Sorter {
    param(
        [string]$InFile = ""
    )

    $FP = Resolve-Path $InFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable fp2
    if (-not($FP)) {
        throw "In file not found: $InFile";
    }


    $lines = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($FP)

    $lines | Sort
}
```

To test this you can wallk through by manually setting `$Infile` to a local text / ini file etc, after you have set `$Lines` you can use `get-member` to see all available methods on the data type:

`$Lines | Get-Member`

Output:

```
TypeName: System.String

Name             MemberType            Definition                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
----             ----------            ----------                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Clone            Method                System.Object Clone(), System.Object ICloneable.Clone()                                                                                                                                                                                 
CompareTo        Method                int CompareTo(System.Object value), int CompareTo(string strB), int IComparable.CompareTo(System.Object obj), int IComparable[string].CompareTo(string other)                                                                           
Contains         Method                bool Contains(string value)                                                                                                                                                                                                             
CopyTo           Method                void CopyTo(int sourceIndex, char[] destination, int destinationIndex, int count)                                                                                                                                                       
EndsWith         Method                bool EndsWith(string value), bool EndsWith(string value, System.StringComparison comparisonType), bool EndsWith(string value, bool ignoreCase, cultureinfo culture)                                                                     
Equals           Method                bool Equals(System.Object obj), bool Equals(string value), bool Equals(string value, System.StringComparison comparisonType), bool IEquatable[string].Equals(string other)                                                              
GetEnumerator    Method                System.CharEnumerator GetEnumerator(), System.Collections.IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator(), System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator[char] IEnumerable[char].GetEnumerator()                                                       
GetHashCode      Method                int GetHashCode()                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
GetType          Method                type GetType()                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
GetTypeCode      Method                System.TypeCode GetTypeCode(), System.TypeCode IConvertible.GetTypeCode()                                                                                                                                                               
IndexOf          Method                int IndexOf(char value), int IndexOf(char value, int startIndex), int IndexOf(string value), int IndexOf(string value, int startIndex), int IndexOf(string value, int startIndex, int count), int IndexOf(string value, System.String...
IndexOfAny       Method                int IndexOfAny(char[] anyOf), int IndexOfAny(char[] anyOf, int startIndex), int IndexOfAny(char[] anyOf, int startIndex, int count)                                                                                                     
Insert           Method                string Insert(int startIndex, string value)                                                                                                                                                                                             
IsNormalized     Method                bool IsNormalized(), bool IsNormalized(System.Text.NormalizationForm normalizationForm)                                                                                                                                                 
LastIndexOf      Method                int LastIndexOf(char value), int LastIndexOf(char value, int startIndex), int LastIndexOf(string value), int LastIndexOf(string value, int startIndex), int LastIndexOf(string value, int startIndex, int count), int LastIndexOf(str...
LastIndexOfAny   Method                int LastIndexOfAny(char[] anyOf), int LastIndexOfAny(char[] anyOf, int startIndex), int LastIndexOfAny(char[] anyOf, int startIndex, int count)                                                                                         
Normalize        Method                string Normalize(), string Normalize(System.Text.NormalizationForm normalizationForm)                                                                                                                                                   
PadLeft          Method                string PadLeft(int totalWidth), string PadLeft(int totalWidth, char paddingChar)                                                                                                                                                        
PadRight         Method                string PadRight(int totalWidth), string PadRight(int totalWidth, char paddingChar)                                                                                                                                                      
Remove           Method                string Remove(int startIndex, int count), string Remove(int startIndex)                                                                                                                                                                 
Replace          Method                string Replace(char oldChar, char newChar), string Replace(string oldValue, string newValue)                                                                                                                                            
Split            Method                string[] Split(Params char[] separator), string[] Split(char[] separator, int count), string[] Split(char[] separator, System.StringSplitOptions options), string[] Split(char[] separator, int count, System.StringSplitOptions opti...
StartsWith       Method                bool StartsWith(string value), bool StartsWith(string value, System.StringComparison comparisonType), bool StartsWith(string value, bool ignoreCase, cultureinfo culture)                                                               
Substring        Method                string Substring(int startIndex), string Substring(int startIndex, int length)                                                                                                                                                          
ToBoolean        Method                bool IConvertible.ToBoolean(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                                                                                                            
ToByte           Method                byte IConvertible.ToByte(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                                                                                                               
ToChar           Method                char IConvertible.ToChar(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                                                                                                               
ToCharArray      Method                char[] ToCharArray(), char[] ToCharArray(int startIndex, int length)                                                                                                                                                                    
ToDateTime       Method                datetime IConvertible.ToDateTime(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                                                                                                       
ToDecimal        Method                decimal IConvertible.ToDecimal(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                                                                                                         
ToDouble         Method                double IConvertible.ToDouble(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                                                                                                           
ToInt16          Method                int16 IConvertible.ToInt16(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                                                                                                             
ToInt32          Method                int IConvertible.ToInt32(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                                                                                                               
ToInt64          Method                long IConvertible.ToInt64(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                                                                                                              
ToLower          Method                string ToLower(), string ToLower(cultureinfo culture)                                                                                                                                                                                   
ToLowerInvariant Method                string ToLowerInvariant()                                                                                                                                                                                                               
ToSByte          Method                sbyte IConvertible.ToSByte(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                                                                                                             
ToSingle         Method                float IConvertible.ToSingle(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                                                                                                            
ToString         Method                string ToString(), string ToString(System.IFormatProvider provider), string IConvertible.ToString(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                                      
ToType           Method                System.Object IConvertible.ToType(type conversionType, System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                                                                                 
ToUInt16         Method                uint16 IConvertible.ToUInt16(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                                                                                                           
ToUInt32         Method                uint32 IConvertible.ToUInt32(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                                                                                                           
ToUInt64         Method                uint64 IConvertible.ToUInt64(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                                                                                                           
ToUpper          Method                string ToUpper(), string ToUpper(cultureinfo culture)                                                                                                                                                                                   
ToUpperInvariant Method                string ToUpperInvariant()                                                                                                                                                                                                               
Trim             Method                string Trim(Params char[] trimChars), string Trim()                                                                                                                                                                                     
TrimEnd          Method                string TrimEnd(Params char[] trimChars)                                                                                                                                                                                                 
TrimStart        Method                string TrimStart(Params char[] trimChars)                                                                                                                                                                                               
Chars            ParameterizedProperty char Chars(int index) {get;}                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Length           Property              int Length {get;}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$f = "C:\Windows\win.ini"
[Collections.Generic.List[string]]$x  = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($f)
$x
$x.Sort()
$x
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and add some commentary to explain your code. Do not expect everyone to understand what you have posted. Explanations are key.